# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 hangs at splash screen, loading icon freezes

Tags: gnome, 15.10

So I've recently installed ubuntu gnome 15.10 on my HP laptop and at first it all runs fine I have all my apps installed that I want but when I reboot it stops at the loading icon and freezes. I've had the problem before but I reinstalled Ubuntu but now its back again, the last few times it happened I could unfreeze the icon by pressing the power button on my laptop, it would begin moving again but would my laptop would shutdown, this no longer happens so I have to kill my laptop to turn it off. I've just booted in like usual from grub and held down shift to see what happens when it freezes and it stops at this point:

[OK] Started User Manager for UID 1000.

Its been at this point for several minutes now. I've tried searching for people with the same problem but their fixes didn't work for me.

Comment: Only just noticed the title it should say freezes.

Comment: This site lets you edit the post - click [edit] below the tags, at the bottom of your question, or click the link above

Comment: Same issue here sadly.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had this problem with Ubuntu 15.10. I installed gnome-shell from the Software Centre and after rebooting it froze on bootup. Looking in syslog I saw the exact same message:

```
[OK] Started User Manager for UID 1000.
```

After searching around, I found this:
[gdm not working with Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689570/gdm-not-working-with-ubuntu-15-10)

Installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, then running `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: After upgrade to ubuntu xenial I had the same problem. Your solution fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell` should fix the problem. Worked for me.

Comment: Please state how this will be done or can be done.

Comment: @George the command is there... I don't know if this can solve the issue though.