# Help! Ubuntu 17.04 Not Booting

Tags: 17.04

I am using Ubuntu 17.04. I decided to install Gnome and Cinnamon desktop environments I was using Virtualbox on gnome when the screen flashed and the computer froze (Dell Inspiron 1121-11z) I used the power button to restart. When I did Ubuntu would no longer boot and it stops on [OK] Started User Manager for UID 132

Comment: These three seem to indicate that a similar problem was caused by a program called GDM failing, and suggest reconfiguring it. This is consistent with your installation of Gnome. https://askubuntu.com/questions/691057/ubuntu-gnome-15-10-hangs-at-splash-screen-loading-icon-freezes https://askubuntu.com/questions/689570/gdm-not-working-with-ubuntu-15-10 https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?33444-Boot-stuck-with-message-quot-OK-Started-User-Manager-for-UID-132-quot

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with GDM3 (the gnome display manager) trying to use Wayland.  Here is how I fixed the issue.

1. Boot and at the grub menu move into (boot from recovery)
2. Drop into a root shell
3. Ensure that lightdm is the login manager by running

   dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
4. Next ensure that gdm3 does not want to use Wayland by editing

   /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

   Add "WaylandEnable=false" to the end of the file
5. reboot