# Ubuntu does not load manager

Tags: gnome, gui, ubuntu-gnome

I installed a Ubuntu 15.10 and GNOME session. The installation was successful but when I restart Ubuntu I see only this and it does not load.How can I solve it?I do not want to install Ubuntu with gnome preinstalled, because all of these versions make my internet slow!

[image]

Comment: How did you install Gnome?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-upgrade-to-gnome-3-16-in-ubuntu-15-04 I've followed these steps, my Ubuntu is 15.10 but I think it is not matter because installation was successful, I've also tried to install gnome via Ubuntu software center with a same result as it is shown in a screenshot.

Comment: I don't know about that, but if you follow the instructions in my answer, you should have Gnome installed and GDM working - although it's probably not the same version as from that PPA. Pretty sure the problem is that you're only installing gnome-shell, and not ubuntu-gnome-desktop.

Comment: The problem was that I only installed gnome shell not Ubuntu-gnome-dekstop as you marked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing how you installed Gnome, I'm guessing something went wrong there.

Please try installing the ubuntu-gnome-desktop package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then reconfigure gdm:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

It solved a similiar issue in 
[gdm not working with Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689570/gdm-not-working-with-ubuntu-15-10)